# Laravel required_without validation with email or numeric validation

Tags: laravel, validation

I'am using laravel's Validator contracts as per below,

```
 return Validator::make($data, [
            'company_name' => 'required',
            'cr_number' => 'required',
            'governorate' => 'required',
            'city' => 'required',
            'block_no' => 'required',
            'road_no' => 'required',
            'building_no' => 'required',
            'office_no' => 'required',
            'firstname' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'lastname' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required_without:phone|email|unique:users',
            'phone' => 'required_without:email|numeric|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'commercial_certificate' => 'required|mimes:pdf|max:5000',
            'vat_certificate' => 'required|mimes:pdf|max:5000'
        ]);
```

Now i wants to do something like if `email is not null` then ignore phone and if `phone is not null` then ignore email , also if `email is not null` then check for valid `email` with `unique in users` and same for phone

**Note :** I also tried with sometimes and nullable

thanks in advnace , cheers ;)

Comment: how have you tried the nullable option??

Comment: Check this answer. [Custom Validation With Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52472150/laravel-validation-depends-on-the-value-of-another-input-field)

Comment: Yes as i mentioned , i tried nullable it's not working @zahidhasanemon

Comment: @brizzy_p I tried solution below by work service , but thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you give this a try? Email will be required if phone is null and vice versa. If filled email will have email validation and check if the same email exists in users table & the same for the phone field too.

```
'email' => 'required_if:phone,null|email|unique:users',
'phone' => 'required_if:email,null|unique:users'
```