# how to make name unique if foreign key is same in laravel validate

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables "rooms" and "beds" i want to unique bed name when room_id is same. what should i do.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $roomid =  $request->input('room_id');

        //
        $attributes = request()->validate([

            'room_id' => ['required', 'integer', 'min:1'],
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:1', 'max:10', 'unique:App\Models\bed,name,room_id' . $roomid],
            'type' => ['nullable', 'string', 'min:1', 'max:10'],
            'description' => ['nullable', 'string', 'min:1', 'max:20']


        ]);
        bed::create($attributes);
}
~~~
```

Comment: If things get compliated you can [use a function for validation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52509783/10441671).

Answer (score 1):

solved

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $roomid =  $request->input('room_id');


        $attributes = request()->validate([

            'room_id' => ['required', 'integer', 'min:1'],
            'name' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'min:1',
                'max:10',
                Rule::unique('beds')
                    ->where(function ($query) {
                        return $query->where('room_id', request('room_id'));
                    })
            ],
            'type' => ['nullable', 'string', 'min:1', 'max:10'],
            'description' => ['nullable', 'string', 'min:1', 'max:20'],
        ]);
        bed::create($attributes);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use closures instead of a rule object because this validation doesn't seem to be necessary throughout your application and you need it only here.

Change your validation to this:

```
        $attributes = request()->validate([

            'room_id' => ['required', 'integer', 'min:1'],
            'name' => [
                'required', 'string', 'min:1','max:10',
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                    
                    // Checke if name is unique in that room
                    $name_exists = \App\Models\Bed::where('name', $value)->where('room_id', request()->input('room_id'))->count() > 0;

                    if ($name_exists) {
                        $fail('The '.$attribute.' must be unique in this room.');
                    }
                }
            ],
            'type' => ['nullable', 'string', 'min:1', 'max:10'],
            'description' => ['nullable', 'string', 'min:1', 'max:20']
        ]);
```

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-closures)